# Pick nested type TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a single type generated from a Swagger API definition.

Each API endpoint has it's API response nested in the Endpoints type. Currently I am accessing like this:

```
type Endpoint1Return = Endpoints['/endpoint1']['get']['responses']['200']['content']['application/json']
type Endpoint2Return = Endpoints['/endpoint2']['get']['responses']['200']['content']['application/json']
```

I want a utility type to pick the nested `application/json` key for each endpoint. Something like:

```
type Endpoint1Return = PickEndpoint<'/endpoint1'>
```

This is difficult because TS doesn't know that each key of `Endpoints` has the same child keys for `get`, `responses`, `200` etc.

Can anyone think of a way to express this?

Comment: Why doesn't TS know that?  What, exactly, is `Endpoints`?  Without a [mcve] I can only guess, and the obvious thing I did to try to reproduce [seems to work without issue](https://tsplay.dev/Lw6b0w).  If I cannot demonstrate the issue for myself then I'm not sure how to help.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for taking a look. I've realised it's not working because not all the API endpoints have a 'get' key, some may only have 'post'. Here's my attempt as building on what you put together: https://tsplay.dev/8w8pPw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your updated question, I'd say this is a bug in TypeScript, as reported in [microsoft/TypeScript#27709](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27709).  It seems that the compiler does not properly evaluate a constraint for nested generic [lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) like `Endpoints[K][L]["responses"]`.  That sub-property lookup type seems to mess things up, as you noticed:

```
type PickEndpointWithMethod<K extends keyof Endpoints, L extends keyof Endpoints[K]> =
    Endpoints[K][L]['responses']['200']['content']['application/json']; // error!
// Type '"responses"' cannot be used to index type 'Endpoints[K][L]'.
// Type '"200"' cannot be used to index type 'Endpoints[K][L]["responses"]'.
// Type '"content"' cannot be used to index type 'Endpoints[K][L]["responses"]["200"]'.
// Type '"application/json"' cannot be used to index type 
//   'Endpoints[K][L]["responses"]["200"]["content"]'.
```

That bug does not seem to be scheduled for fixing anytime soon.

---

As a workaround, you could calculate the constraint of an indexed access yourself, and use the [`Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to hint to the compiler that the lookup type does meet that constraint:

```
type Idx<T, K extends keyof T> = Extract<T[K], T extends any ? T[keyof T] : never>;
```

Here, we are assuring the compiler that `T[K]` will extend `T[keyof T]` even if `T` is a union of things.  (The `T extends any ? T[keyof T]: never` construction uses [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to do so).  Then we can replace, `Endpoints[K][L]` with `Idx<Endpoints[K], L>`, like so:

```
type PickEndpointWithMethod<K extends keyof Endpoints, L extends keyof Endpoints[K]> =
    Idx<Endpoints[K], L>['responses']['200']['content']['application/json']; // okay
```

Let's see if it works:

```
type Endpoint1Return = PickEndpointWithMethod<'/endpoint1', 'get'>
// type Endpoint1Return = "https://example.com/foo"
type Endpoint2Return = PickEndpointWithMethod<'/endpoint2', 'post'>
// type Endpoint2Return = "https://example.com/bar"
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIgCYAcD2owDOyA3gFDIXIBEA9BJrvgIxUBcJyA5hGO8clAgFcIAkL7UATAAZpbDghzh6vDlThYsAG2AI4YYEpoArAkvlUAFmDBYCrGnQAecALbaIAOkWuaMHDhUyAC+IWGhweSUtPTYeOCS8vy4BKr8gsJKYvZqMnISisrgEuqaOnoGRqbm7FY2dg7Obh7eOL4ARnBQQRHhIaSRpGAAnlgoAJIYTgA8ACoANMgA0sgQTpCYRADWEMM4MMizAHzIALxo61CIYHMA2ksAuouzq+uxRHAgw8gA-Ie3Oz2B1mD2Q7BAEAAbtAjgBuUhDUYoAAKui26Di+AA6sAwJYALI8Sw4DDTFZrDYYba7fZoBjxQiLAAyr0p1KBdMx4AI9weJ1OUQokxmGMY3N5zKOtwA5BkRNlpQ8ZXlFTLChswKrpRptLp9IYQCYzCBFbDkI5kDgtnBhgiRmNOWKwEwAEo8ACuUBAZ2QqIQ6Pp2NxBKJJOm0rogfATGli2l3E1R1IFvtKFFDNdHq9PrqtnsjjWzS0Xh8fgCVERDvT+EkbrAnu95z9Aa5YBxeMJeLDEdiTskseQ0pSieTNGQqcdDNrWcb1GsecahfcxdaHS6VCAA)

Comment: Thank you, that's great!